# Compare record and add entry to temp and update temp particular column value in oracle for 10000 records

Tags: oracle, plsql

I think I would need to rephrase the info: (I don't how to write a code for this)

Table name : test1

Here is examples which give what exactly I'm looking for
**Example 1**

Initial Table
Name    Ref Start date  End date
5001    KLM123  01/01/2011  31/05/2012
5001    KLM111  01/06/2012  31/12/2012
**5001  KLM112  01/01/2013  31/12/2013
5001    KLM112  01/01/2014  31/12/2014**

Final Table
Name    Ref Start date  End date
5001    KLM123  01/01/2011  31/05/2012
5001    KLM111  01/06/2012  31/12/2012
**5001  KLM112  01/01/2013  31/12/2014** (Record 3 and 4 are compressed into one given start date and end date since Name and Ref remains same in this period)

**Example 2**

Initial Table
Name    Ref Start date  End date
5001    KLM123  01/01/2011  31/05/2012
5001    KLM111  01/06/2012  31/12/2012
**5001  KLM112  01/01/2013  31/12/2013
5001    KLM112  01/01/2014  12/12/2014**
5001    KLM134  01/01/2015  30/06/2015
5001    KLM133  01/07/2015  31/12/2015
5002    KLM144  01/01/2013  31/12/2013
5002    KLM155  01/01/2014  12/12/2014

Final Table
Name    Ref Start date  End date
5001    KLM123  01/01/2011  31/05/2012
5001    KLM111  01/06/2012  31/12/2012
**5001  KLM112  01/01/2013  31/12/2014**
5001    KLM134  01/01/2015  30/06/2015
5001    KLM133  01/07/2015  31/12/2015
5002    KLM144  01/01/2013  31/12/2013
5002    KLM155  01/01/2014  12/12/2014

Would like to have "Final table" as another table. So what is best and optimal way to do this in PL/SQL?

Thnx

Answer (score 0):

```
With CTE as
(Select ID, name, Ref, Start_date, max(End_date) 
from test1 group by ID, Name, Ref, Start_date)
Select T1.ID, T1.Name, T1.Ref, T1.Start_date, T1.End_date
From CTE t1
```

Change this to an insert and I think it will do what your asking...

I think you want unique records from test1 based on ID, Name, Ref and start date.  and when there isn't a unique value, you want the MAX end date.